# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MvcInterop.InteropMasterPage'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I am receiving this error when running an ASP.NET MVC 5.27 application.  I am running Visual Studio 2017.  I have all the web developer tools installed for Visual Studio.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MvcInterop.InteropMasterPage'.